# AngularJS - how to change an object from parent crtl in the child ctrl without using scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

How to change an object from parent crtl in the child ctrl without using `$scope`?

Example:

```
myApp.controller("ParentController", function () {
    var pvm = this;
    pvm.index = 0;
});
myApp.controller("ChildController", function () {
    var cvm = this;
    pvm.index = 1; // how to achieve this?
});
```

Comment: because we are just organizing code that way...following the style guides...

Comment: Emit and Broadcast will help you. But without `$scope` you can use shared service

Comment: @RashadIbrahimov I tried using shared service, but when I update a service `state` object through child ctrl, the parent ctrl's object that is referencing the service `state` object doesn't get updated.

Comment: You can use service as shared resource between two controllers. But if you want some data dynamically get updated you have to use event listener (emit and broadcast). Sorry, but no other way.

Comment: @tasseKATT I used a shared service.

Comment: @tasseKATT I upvoted Rashad Ibrahimov's comment which gave me a hint. I didn't use the solution as you suggested.